# Track Individual User Activity in the Site through Analytic

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, flurry

We would like to track each individual user (logged in user) activity in the site.

Here is the list of activities :

1) Page View
2) Button click
3) Search keywords
etc.

Is there any way we can achieve this by Flurry or Google analytic or any other analytic.

Answer (score 0):

With Universal Analytics, you can enable the new User ID feature which tracks logged in users as a custom dimension. You can view various reports against that custom dimension. There's more info here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123663.